# How to transform XML using XSLT in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt

I have an XML and XSLT and want to apply the transformation using JavaScript and save the result as ".txt" file. 
any help ?
This is a part of my code

```
                  reader.onload = function(e) {
                  var contents = e.target.result;
                  parser = new DOMParser();
                  xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(contents, "text/xml");
                  var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM")
                  xsl.async = false
                  xsl.load("2.xsl")
                 // Transform
                 document.write(xml.transformNode(xsl));
                 new Transformation().setXml(xmlDoc)
                 .setXslt(xsl).transform("transformResult");
                }
```

Comment: Where do you expect to save a text file with client-side Javascript? On your server? Or on the client? Or in which context do you use Javascript? `ActiveXObject` looks like IE or classic ASP, `DOMParser` looks like client-side script in any modern browser besides IE. I have no idea where the `Transformation` function comes from.

Comment: yes both files are on my local PC